# Leaf scorch on perennials from fertiliser

Tags: fertilizer

Fertiliser was applied correctly but some of the leaves were wet and it was only watered off after signs of scorch and wilt.  The leaves are scorched on some of the plants.   Will the plants put on new good growth or is will this kill the plant? Thanks

Comment: Which plants and how big are they, quite small or quite large? which fertiliser? a photo might also help...

Comment: Small perennials geranium phaeum, papaver, foxgloves, dayllies , stachys etc . Most are just starting to grow up. The ones that seemed to have really suffered were the geranium. I do not have a photo to show.